# Must jQuery UI Droppable be combined with Draggable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am using jQuery UI Draggable and Droppable and I have a special condition where I also have drag and drop functionality from a third part library.

I can't manage to use Droppable together with this library, so dear stackoverflowers, must I have assigned Draggable to any element for Droppable to work? In that case, why?

**EDIT:**
I am using Telerik's RadOrgChart with their Drag and Drop. I want to accomplish dropping both on the RadOrgChart (I am moving nodes in the tree) and on an element outside the RadOrgChart (this is why I need jQuery). I will use the drop zone outside the chart for deleting nodes.

Comment: the meaning of droppable is to be a target for a draggable element, so yes. I wonder what is your third party library and what are you trying to achieve, please post some code and info on that other library

Comment: @G.Mendes I edited the question. I managed to set draggable to the aldready dragged item by using the jquery mousedown and start draggable after a short timeout (it wouldn't work without timeout since teleriks drag would not have been set up before the mousedown). It still gives me some problems but I am a lot closer to the solution. Write an answer of your comment and I'll give you the credits :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly to jquery ui docs, the selector element that becomes droppable will then accept to be dropped on by draggable elements, in order to be able to use ui droppable functionality towards other elements, these other elements must be ui-draggable, more info at [jquery-ui droppable](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/)